# How do I specify an input file for Watson NLU using a curl command?

Tags: curl, nlp, ibm-watson

I've got a text file that I want to feed into Watson's Natural Language Understanding service via a curl command and would like to know how to indicate this on the data I'm passing to the service. I've gotten it to work using a URL but want to use a different source. In the example below I want to replace "I love apples! I do not like oranges." with a file name. Thanks.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
"{url}/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12" \
--request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "text": "I love apples! I do not like oranges.",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {
      "targets": [
        "apples",
        "oranges",
        "broccoli"
      ]
    },
    "keywords": {
      "emotion": true
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the --data parameters as a .json file, to include the text, but the other query parameters also need to be included.

From the API documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#analyze-text

```
 curl -X POST -u "apikey":"{apikey}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @parameters.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"
```

where parameters.json looks something like:

```
 {
   "text": "IBM is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Armonk, New York, United States, with operations in over 170 countries.",
   "features": {
     "entities": {
       "emotion": true,
       "sentiment": true,
       "limit": 2
     },
     "keywords": {
       "emotion": true,
       "sentiment": true,
       "limit": 2
     }
   }
 }
```